# In ExoPlayer how do I show the thumbnail of the first frame after loading a media source and seeking to a position instead of it being blank?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

How do I show the first frame of the video after the Fragment is resumed instead of the video player being blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Add surface_type="texture_view" to `PlayerView`

```
 <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_view"
    app:surface_type="texture_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

2.) Add thumbnail view in front of PlayerView in layout

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_thumbnail_background"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_thumbnail"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

3.) Create a method to get the `Bitmap` from the `TextureView`

```
private fun setVideoThumbnail() {
    val textureView = playerView.videoSurfaceView as TextureView
    val bitmap = textureView.bitmap
    thumbnailImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    thumbnailBackground.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    thumbnailImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

4.) In `onPause` call

```
setVideoThumbnail()
// destroy player or not depending
```

5.) Add an `onClick` listener to thumbnailImage in `onViewCreated`

```
thumbnailImage.setOnClickListener {
    // make sure player is re-created and media source is loaded, prepared, and seekTo
    player.playWhenReady = true

    thumbnailBackground.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    thumbnailImage.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

Comment: From https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/8975